# Adding a JTextPane to BorderLayout.SOUTH causes JScrollPane to scroll

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane, caret

I have a JPanel which is contained within a JScrollPane.  The JPanel has components added to it's NORTH, CENTER, WEST and SOUTH areas (BorderLayout).

When I add a JTextPane to the SOUTH position, the scroll pane scrolls to show the text.  I do not want the scroll pane to move from its topmost position.  How can I prevent this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291353/jscrollpane-scrollbar-jumps-down-on-jeditorpane-settext

Comment: Yes, that [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11291548/230513) also works.

Answer (score 3):

Absent more details, you can try setting the default caret to [`NEVER_UPDATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultCaret.html#NEVER_UPDATE), available since Java 5.

```
JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane();
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) jtp.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
```