# Put the bar of a JScrollPane scroll bar at XXX without "flashing"

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I'm building a `JScrollPane` to set scrollable a `JPanel` which contains a `JTextPane` and a `JTable`.

When I load the frame I initialize the `JTextPane` with a very long text, then the scroll bar moves down til the end of my document.

I'd like to get this scroll bar on top of the document instead. So I put the value of my scroll bar to 0, after the text loading:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
    }
});
```

It works fine (i.e. I get the scroll bar on top) but the rendered behavior is pretty ugly. Now it loads the text, shows the end (with the scroll bar at the bottom of the text pane), then immediately (few milliseconds, but still visible) moves up to get the scroll bar on top. The resulting effect is a "flash" for the user, which is very unpleasant. And I have the same problem each time I reload the whole document.

How could I avoid that?

Thanks.

Comment: Not setting frame.setVisible(true) until after you've set the scroll bar to zero?

Comment: But it does not work if all my components are already instantiated and when I only want to "reload" the whole document. For instance: all the frame is visible, I click on a JButton which replaces all the "hello" words (in the document) with "HELLO". The document is rewrited in my text pane, but the scroll bar is again at the bottom of it. :/
Thank you guys.

Comment: See also this [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11299764/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I put the default caret to [`NEVER_UPDATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultCaret.html#NEVER_UPDATE).

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textPane.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultCaret.html#setUpdatePolicy%28int%29) is the documentation of `setUpdatePolicy()`. Then I update the caret by myself.

Comment: Nice one, didn't know about that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

You could simply set the caret position in your `JTextPane` to 0 after updating its content but before creating `JScrollPane`. That will force `JScrollPane` to show the begining of text right away without pointless scrolling backward.

Just do something like this:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane ();
textPane.setText ( "Some long text here..." );
textPane.setCaretPosition ( 0 );

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane ( textPane );
```

If you already have text - just do the update and caret position switch together in EDT:

```
public static void main ( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
{
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame ();

    final JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane ();
    frame.add ( new JScrollPane ( textPane ) );

    frame.setSize ( 400, 300 );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
    frame.setVisible ( true );

    Thread.sleep ( 2000 );
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable ()
    {
        public void run ()
        {
            textPane.setText ( "line\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline" +
                    "\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline" +
                    "\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline" +
                    "\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline" );
            textPane.setCaretPosition ( 0 );
        }
    } );

    Thread.sleep ( 2000 );
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable ()
    {
        public void run ()
        {
            textPane.setText ( "line2\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline" +
                    "\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline" +
                    "\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline" +
                    "\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline" );
            textPane.setCaretPosition ( 0 );
        }
    } );
}
```

But i agree that it is not the best solution. I guess there is no easy way to force textpane caret to be at 0 when its content changes.

Comment: See my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567668/put-the-bar-of-a-jscrollpane-scroll-bar-at-xxx-without-flashing/12568063#comment16931693_12567668

Comment: @MarcdeVerdelhan you should set textpane content and caret position one after another in EDT, in that case pane will be visually updated only after caret position set. See the example in my answer.

Comment: Thanks to you and to @trashgod I understand better how the caret is managed in the EDT (with `adjustVisibility()`, etc.). I chose the [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11299764/230513) given by @trashgod but your way works fine too. Thank you guys.