# Cant add text to JEditorPane with text/html

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

I have a `JEditorPane` in my class and am trying to add text to it. (I didn't use a text area or pane because it has to support certain things like HTML)

The problem I have is (my `JEditorPane` is called chatLog), when I type `chatLog.setContentType("text/html");` and type `chatLog.setText("Test");`
Nothing happens...

The second I comment out/remove `chatLog.setContentType("text/html");` the text that should be appearing, appears fine.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

**Source:**

```
public ServerGUI() {
    // Rest of code above.

    JEditorPane chatLog = new JEditorPane();
    chatLog.setContentType("text/html");
    chatLog.setEditable(false);

    // Rest of code below.
}

public void appendText(String str) {
    // Can use a word instead of str too like the "Test" above.
    chatLog.setText(chatLog.getText() + str);
    //chatLog.setCaretPosition(chatLog.getText().length() - 1);
}
```

And also, just another little problem I have which isnt too major, I cant set the caret position as seen above when I have the content type to HTML. It says there is an `IllegalArgument Exception`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think that you have an x --> y problem, nothing clear from this question - voting to close as too broad, (how and if is XxxEditorKit used, override or initialized), [but shot into the dark .... by @Guillaume Polet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11291548/714968)

Comment: Or well, it has been solved now so not to worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you append new text like this:

```
chatLog.setText(chatLog.getText() + str);
```

So you append text to the current content. If you set `text/html` content type and you never call `JEditorPane.setText()`, it still has some default HTML code. This default HTML code ends with a proper `</html>` closing tag. Now if you append anything to an HTML text, that will be after the `</html>` closing tag so it will not be rendered.

To demonstrate it:

```
JEditorPane chatLog = new JEditorPane();
chatLog.setContentType("text/html");
System.out.println(chatLog.getText()); // This will print an HTML document
```

The empty HTML document has a `<body>` tag and an empty `<p>` tag, something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="margin-top: 0">

    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Proposed solution:**

Use `JEditorPane.getDocument()`. If you set `text/html` content type, by default the returned `Document` will be an instance of [HTMLDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html) which you can use to add new elements for new chat messages.

Comment: Whenever I call it a second time, it appears but not in a HTML format?

Comment: Oops, my mistake, just had it bold. :P

Comment: Also, thanks, that has solved all my problems, now I just got to fix up my HTML and make it stylish :P